# CSS - Full width sticky footer with constant width content

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I want to use CSS to create a 'sticky' footer that sticks to the bottom of the page if the height of the page content doesn't exceed the browser height. However I want the header and footer to fill the whole width of the screen, with a fixed-width content block in between which extends the full height between the two. The closest I have got is the example below, however I can't get the grey content block to fill the whole height between the header and the footer.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fff;
    }
    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    #header {
        background: #ff0;
        height: 40px;
    }
    #content {
        padding: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 40px; /* Height of the footer */
        width: 700px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background: grey;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px; /* Height of the footer */
        background: #6cf;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```css
html,body{ 
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: #ff0;
  height: 40px;
}
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: grey;
  min-height: calc(100% - 40px - 40px - 20px); /* 100% - height of header - height of footer - vertical padding */
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; /* Height of the footer */
  background: #6cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque at quam ut rutrum. Pellentesque at molestie leo, sit amet sagittis velit. Morbi dapibus ante finibus nulla finibus, eget semper risus lobortis. Nullam in metus non felis egestas hendrerit id non libero. Donec auctor non est ut venenatis. Nulla non tortor ac urna sodales sagittis. Sed blandit arcu a mi venenatis consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Maecenas vel quam purus. Praesent sed eleifend felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin posuere tristique consequat. Fusce congue tortor sed lorem eleifend, sit amet malesuada turpis varius. Pellentesque pretium, velit quis posuere dignissim, nisl velit eleifend nisi, eleifend scelerisque magna libero non nisl. Nullam dapibus sem a ligula cursus, a iaculis lacus scelerisque. Sed sed enim tincidunt, vehicula felis eu, gravida erat. Vestibulum lectus neque, lobortis a varius quis, vestibulum vitae dolor. Curabitur vitae rutrum diam. Nulla facilisi. Proin molestie mi rhoncus, feugiat metus sed, hendrerit risus. Cras et pulvinar tellus, in fringilla turpis.

Praesent auctor tortor ut dolor fermentum, eu facilisis nisi congue. Donec ac nulla rhoncus, condimentum libero vitae, congue ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis faucibus nisi at feugiat aliquam. Quisque tempus malesuada ligula sed ornare. Cras ac urna ut leo vehicula efficitur nec quis elit. Aenean rhoncus molestie neque eget porttitor. Quisque nec dignissim metus. Vivamus mattis sem in consectetur fringilla.

Sed dapibus, eros in ultricies suscipit, sapien risus tincidunt nisi, ultricies efficitur mi justo vel massa. Vestibulum mollis fermentum augue, non suscipit mauris ullamcorper a. Praesent eu vulputate mauris. Suspendisse luctus nisi turpis, sit amet ultrices lorem molestie in. Nam vel lorem cursus, varius diam vitae, finibus sem. Duis ac euismod ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Cras tristique nisi at ex lacinia, id gravida nibh venenatis. Aliquam lorem urna, pulvinar a sem in, ullamcorper mollis arcu. Ut in ex vestibulum, rhoncus nisi eu, posuere diam. Ut at justo euismod, hendrerit est non, pharetra augue. Duis ut lacus enim. Nam rhoncus ornare sapien, vitae rhoncus dui placerat nec. Nulla pulvinar, leo ut semper posuere, ante odio dignissim nulla, ac vehicula nisl nisl id velit. Nam dictum leo nunc, in lobortis tellus imperdiet at. Sed turpis orci, dapibus a mollis vitae, dapibus eu tellus. Curabitur mauris felis, venenatis a mattis quis, venenatis et mauris. Aenean sodales turpis non fringilla iaculis. Morbi porta euismod ligula, in tincidunt nisl ullamcorper eget. Nullam aliquet eros eu maximus tincidunt. Ut rutrum quam nec eros lacinia blandit. Integer dignissim egestas diam sed ullamcorper. Aliquam cursus pharetra urna, ut tristique risus feugiat sit amet.</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I used calc for this and some browsers do not yet support it. Take a look at [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for more information.

Comment: I have not heard of calc, but I encountered situations several times when something like that was needed. I have always resolved those situations with Javascript. Question: is there a non-Javascript alternative for calc for the browsers which do not support it as a fallback logic?

Comment: This does the job, thanks! I'll keep the question open in case there is a solution with more cross-browser support.

Comment: @LajosArpad Calc came along with CSS3, and as far as I am aware this is the most supported method to create this effect. There is flex which could probably do the same thing, however that has even worse browser compatibility and I think it would take longer to achieve this effect.

 Personally, I think this the best way to do it using pure CSS, JavaScript could do this easily and there is plenty of content on the web  already so I won't go into details here.

Comment: Although I've just realised it doesn't work when the content is longer than the browser window, as the footer stays at the bottom of the window rather than the bottom of the content. Changing height:100% to min-height:100% in the css seems to fix it though.

Comment: Good spot Chris! That's now been updated in my answer :)

Comment: @LajosArpad Well by the looks of it all seems well when I try it out, and there's no comments about it at this [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=min-height).